# Index files using R and Elastic

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I like to index files using ES and R. I've installed R the Ingest Attachment Processor Plugin. I've also installed the R package *elastic*. Is it possible to create an attachment pipeline from R? I can't find something like **ingest** in the *elastic*-package.

I like to apply the following tutorial https://qbox.io/blog/how-to-index-attachments-and-files-to-elasticsearch-5-0-using-ingest-api

Comment: `elastic` maintainer here. note that we do have an open issue for the ingest routes https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues/191 - you can watch that issue to get progress on that feature

Comment: see https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues/191#issuecomment-405722185